# How to create a copy of a file with multipe ranges of columns removed in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, cut

I want to make a copy of a file with fixed-width records with multiple numeric ranges removed. For example a file has fixed width records 1600 long,  and I want to keep columns 0-83, 89-1517, 1526-end.  This is for use in a larger problem, standalone utilities like cut and awk won't help here.

I have this which I apply to each line/record; it works okay, wonder if anything obviously better.

```
"".join([full[:84], full[89:1518], full[1526:]])
```

In particular I'd find it more natural to specify what to cut than what to keep, if there's standard library or easy to read quick function that is more like

```
 # hypothetical
 cut(line, [ [84,88], [1519, 25] ])
```

**ADDITION**

To accepted answer, use sorted list of cuts, so caller can give in any order.  Would be nice to add overlap detection as well

```
def cut(line, cuts):
    sorted_cuts = sorted(cuts, key=lambda x: x[0])
    
    return ''.join(line[slice(keep_start, keep_end)]
                   for keep_start, keep_end in zip(
                           [None] + [cut_end for cut_start, cut_end in sorted_cuts],
                           [cut_start for cut_start, cut_end in sorted_cuts] + [None]))


origline = "0123456789"

assert (cut(origline, [[1,2], [3,4]]) ==
        cut(origline, ([3,4], (1,2))) ==
        cut(origline, [[3,4], [1,2]]))

print(cut(origline, [[1,2], [3,4]]))
```

Comment: If they're a list, you can just index like you are above but use del

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of your hypothetical `cut` function.

```
def cut(line, cuts):
    
    return ''.join(line[slice(keep_start, keep_end)]
                   for keep_start, keep_end in zip(
                           [None] + [cut_end for cut_start, cut_end in cuts],
                           [cut_start for cut_start, cut_end in cuts] + [None]))

print(cut('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', [[1,3], [9,10]]))
```

gives:

```
adefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

(`bc` and `j` were cut)

So:

- the slice to keep goes from the start to the start of the first cut,
- the slice to keep goes from the end of the first cut to the start of the second cut
- ...
- the last slice to keep goes from the end of the last cut to the end of the string

The `[None] + [cut_end for cut_start, cut_end in cuts]` is the start of each slice to keep, in this example `[None, 3, 10]`

The `[cut_start for cut_start, cut_end in cuts] + [None]` is the end of each slice to keep, in this example `[1, 9, None]`

where `None` means start/end of string as used by the `slice` builtin.

---

---

Note: to implement the cuts given in your example, you would supply the arguments to this `cut` function as:

```
 cut(line, [[84, 89], [1519, 1526]])
```

where the second element of each 2-element list is the index *after* the end of the cut, in keeping with normal python indexing conventions.

If you really want *not* to have to do this (in order to get *exactly* the `cut` function that you describe above), then in the above code you would replace:

```
[cut_end for cut_start, cut_end in cuts]
```

with:

```
[cut_end + 1 for cut_start, cut_end in cuts]
```

For convenience, here is the full code of the function in that case, and the calling code that you would use in your example:

```
def cut(line, cuts):
    
    return ''.join(line[slice(keep_start, keep_end)]
                   for keep_start, keep_end in zip(
                           [None] + [cut_end + 1 for cut_start, cut_end in cuts],
                           [cut_start for cut_start, cut_end in cuts] + [None]))

print(cut(line, [[84, 88], [1519, 1525]])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great.  Accepted. My contribution appended to original post allows the cuts to be given in any order.